# How to ask for specific result in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I prepared a Prolog solution of a riddle about people living in a three-floor block with two sides(left,right) - so 6 flats. The solution is correct. The code for solution is below:

What I want to achieve is to have three different predicates answer1/1, answer2/2, answer3/3 where:

1. Answer1/1 - returns information about all people, I think that clues(Left,Right) already does that, however I think that /1 means the number of arguments in predicate. Is it possible to make it with just one argument?
2. Answer2/2 - returns information about person with certain attribute, let's say it's supposed to show citizen with first attribute equal to 'wladyslaw'.
3. Answer3/3 - returns information about people from the left side of building (so those, who are mentioned in parameter Left in Answer1/1.

I wonder, whether this slash and value means number of parameters and if so - is it possible to make it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 variables for each person - their floor (numbered 1-3, with 3 being ground), and their block (left or right, i.e. 1 or 2).

Your clue1, clue2 etc. are kinda cheating because they are specifying the floor and block of the persons.

Here is not-completely-tested code, with lots of clues:

```
% Like nth1, but for multiple lists
% LN is list number, starting at 1
nth1_lists(N, [H|T], E, LN) :-
    nth1_lists_(T, H, N, E, 1, LN).

nth1_lists_(_, H, N, E, LN, LN) :-
    nth1(N, H, E).
nth1_lists_([H|T], _, N, E, LN0, LN) :-
    LN1 is LN0 + 1,
    nth1_lists_(T, H, N, E, LN1, LN).


% Changes to plural - presumably don't care which block
in_blocks(P, Blocks) :-
    % Don't care which pos or block
    nth1_lists(_, Blocks, P, _).

lives_above(X, Y, Blocks) :-
    % Same block B
    nth1_lists(XN, Blocks, X, B),
    nth1_lists(YN, Blocks, Y, B),
    XN < YN.

lives_near(X, Y, Blocks) :-
    % Different block, same pos
    dif(XB, YB),
    nth1_lists(Pos, Blocks, X, XB),
    nth1_lists(Pos, Blocks, Y, YB).

lives_1_floor_above(X, Y, Blocks) :-
    % Pos 1 is highest, pos 3 is ground floor
    nth1_lists(XN, Blocks, X, _),
    nth1_lists(YN, Blocks, Y, _),
    YN is XN + 1.

lives_between(X, Y, Z, Blocks) :-
    dif(C, =),
    % Same block
    nth1_lists(XN, Blocks, X, B),
    nth1_lists(YN, Blocks, Y, B),
    nth1_lists(ZN, Blocks, Z, B),
    % Same comparison sign
    compare(C, XN, YN),
    compare(C, YN, ZN).

% Removed person Y - only care about person X
on_left(X, Blocks) :-
    % Left block is block 1
    nth1_lists(_, Blocks, X, 1).

ground_floor(X, Blocks) :-
    % Don't care which block
    nth1(3, Blocks, X, _).

clues(Blocks) :-
    % Size of blocks
    length(Blocks, 2),
    maplist(length(3), Blocks),
    % Or just use: Blocks = [[_,_,_], [_,_,_]],
    % clue1
    lives_above(karmikanarki, wkazdejchwili, Blocks),
    % clue2
    lives_near(weronika, o4rano, Blocks),
    lives_near(zamiatachodniki, wladyslaw, Blocks).
    % and so on, up to clue 13


answer1(Blocks) :-
    clues(Blocks).

answer2(Person, Pos-Block) :-
    clues(Blocks),
    nth1_lists(Pos, Blocks, Person, Block).

% Unsure whether Block is desired in arguments
answer3(Person, Pos-Block) :-
    clues(Blocks),
    % Person is in block 1
    on_left(Person, Blocks),
    nth1_lists(Pos, Blocks, Person, Block).
```

Comment: I mean, I am not allowed to use lists in my solution and I am allowed to use such "cheats" - hints/clues written in natural language suggest the position. What I need is specifically the answer 1/answer2 and answer3 based on my code.

Comment: You can use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=arg/3 to determine the position of elements in your `citizen/3` term. Is that what's wanted? Is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> Answer1/1 - returns information about all people, I think that clues(Left,Right) already does that, however I think that /1 means the number of arguments in predicate. Is it possible to make it with just one argument?

Yes the `/1` does mean the number of arguments (it's called the 'arity'). Change `clues(Left,Right) :-` to `clues(Left-Right) :-` and it is one argument. Just change that header and the way you query it, nothing else.

> Answer2/2 - returns information about person with certain attribute, let's say it's supposed to show citizen with first attribute equal to 'wladyslaw'.

Your comment to @brebs says you cannot use lists, so you cannot use member/2. Here is a way:

```
answer2(Name, Citizen) :- 
    clues(left(L1, L2, L3)-right(R1, R2, R3)),
    ( (L1 = citizen(Name, _, _), Citizen = L1)
    ; (L2 = citizen(Name, _, _), Citizen = L2)
    ; (L3 = citizen(Name, _, _), Citizen = L3)
    ; (R1 = citizen(Name, _, _), Citizen = R1)
    ; (R2 = citizen(Name, _, _), Citizen = R2)
    ; (R3 = citizen(Name, _, _), Citizen = R3)).
```

> Answer3/3 - returns information about people from the left side of building (so those, who are mentioned in parameter Left in Answer1/1.

```
answer3(L1, L2, L3) :-
    clues(left(L1, L2, L3)-_).
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Could I ask for more explanation about change to Left-Right? I guess then I should change inside of all predicates to left(-,-,-)-right(-,-,-) and that's it, am I right? I don't quite understand how it works. Is "-" some kind of operator?

Comment: "*I guess then I should change inside of all predicates*" - no, that's why I added "just change the header and nothing else". Dash is not any kind of operator, it's two things bound together with a line. It's how you write a pair or tuple in Prolog. Like `(A,B)` is a single tuple with two things in Python, or `[A,B]`  is a single list with two items, in Prolog `-(A,B)` is a single term with two arguments and it can be written `A-B` as a single pair with two items. "I have to have a single argument" -> change the two arguments into a single argument which is a pair of the two things.